# Scrapy download data from links where certain other condition is fulfilled

Tags: python, scrapy

I am extracting data from Imdb lists and it is working fine. I provide a link for all lists related to an imdb title, the code opens all lists and can pretty extract data what I want.

```
class lisTopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'ImdbListsSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.imdb.com/lists/tt2218988'
    ]

    #lists related to given title
    def parse(self, response):
        #Grab list link section
        listsLinks = response.xpath('//div[2]/strong')

        for link in listsLinks:
            list_url = response.urljoin(link.xpath('.//a/@href').get())
                yield scrapy.Request(list_url, callback=self.parse_list, meta={'list_url': list_url})
```

Now what is the issue, is that I want this code to skip all lists that have more than 50 titles and get data where lists have less than 50 titles.
Problem with it is that list link is in separate block of xpath and number of titles is in another block.
[image]

So I tried the following.

```
for link in listsLinks:
        list_url = response.urljoin(link.xpath('.//a/@href').get())
        numOfTitlesString = response.xpath('//div[@class="list_meta"]/text()[1]').get()
        numOfTitles = int(''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isdigit(), numOfTitlesString)))
        print ('numOfTitles' , numOfTitles)
        if numOfTitles < 51:
            yield scrapy.Request(list_url, callback=self.parse_list, meta={'list_url': list_url})
```

But it gives me empty csv file. When I try to print numOfTitles in for loop, it gives me result of very first xpath found for all rounds of the loop.

Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: This is the typical “You are missing a ‘.’ at the beginning of your XPath expression” issue :)

Comment: Hi, I tried it, it should work but it is giving even worse result as follows;
numOfTitles = int(''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isdigit(), numOfTitlesString)))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: So you need to review that XPath expression further, it seems to return `None` now. Maybe it needs to use `..` or something else to first find a parent element that contains the target `div`.

Comment: can you provide an example link to the page you want to run the xpath on to get the number of total titles

Comment: I may be wrong but I think we add '.' only in case where we want to join the xpath with previous xpath result. In this case '//div[@class="list_meta"]/text()[1]' is stand alone text and it works fine for first link. But when loop goes forward to next links, this specific xpath keeps showing titles of first list only instead of showing title numbers of following lists.

Comment: @Chase, the url is given as start_urls https://www.imdb.com/lists/tt2218988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gallaecio mentioned, it's just an xpath issue. It's normal you keep getting the same number, because you're executing the exact same xpath to the exact same response object. In the below code we get the whole block (instead of just the part that contains the url), and for every block we get the url and the number of titles.

```
list_blocks = response.xpath('//*[has-class("list-preview")]')
for block in list_blocks:
    list_url = response.urljoin(block.xpath('./*[@class="list_name"]//@href').get())
    number_of_titles_string = block.xpath('./*[@class="list_meta"]/text()').get()
    number_of_titles = int(''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isdigit(), number_of_titles_string)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really didn't know this concept. Works greatly!!!